# How can I see the permissions of a specific directory?

Tags: command-line

I know that I can use `ls -l` to list all the files in a directory including their permissions, but how do I see the permissions of a specific directory. For example if I wanted to see the permissions for my `/etc` directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `-d` to the command like so:

```
ls -ld /etc
```

From `man ls`:

```
   -d, --directory
          list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links
```

Answer (score 7):

Also you can use [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/stat.1.html) command to getting permissions of specific file or directory:

```bsh
 stat -c "%A %n" Directory-or-File
```

or permission in octal mode:

```bsh
 stat -c "%a %n" Directory-or-File
```

- The `-c` option allows you to customize the output.
- The file’s name is shown as a result of `%n`, `%a` shows octal permissions and `%A` shows permissions in human readable form.